# How to pass parameter to struts2 action class using URL

Tags: java, xml, url, struts2, gmail

I am developing Email Verification code when new user register to the system. When the user fill the registration form and click the submit button system send the activation URL with encrypted username. Below I mentioned the URL that I am sending.

http://localhost:8080/webplatform/getVarifiedLogin.action?loginuser=3385a6e7d0ce17f3e4383a390256f7a9

When the user click on the URL it should execute particular action. It is ok. It executes particular action. I want to send this encrypted value to action class. So can you please tell me how can I do configuration in struts.xml and action class to do this.

Comment: Post your action class and configuration.

Answer (score 1):

With what I understand from your question,

On your action class, you will need

```
private String loginuser;
//its getter setter
```

once you click url, your action class loginuser will have loginuser value passed through url.

Comment: Already I have set getter and setter for loginguser. But when I print loginuser in execute method it print as null

Comment: it should be loginuser not loginguser;

Comment: yes. that is my mistake. In my code it is right :(

Comment: I would do two things. 1. Debug on browser to see what is exact url. 2. debug your action class and see what exactly you are getting